# Set Path variable in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have just moved to Linux (Ubuntu 15.04) and I am trying to add my python directory (:~/Documents/Python/Programs) to the path variable, but I am struggling..

I have tried export PATH = $PATH:~/Documents/Python/Programs, and then turning off and on again, but nothing happens
I have also looked at my ~/.profile, but don't under stand it, it comes up with (I have removed a tonnes of comments from the top):

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

UPDATE:
What I am trying to do is add my python directory to PATH so that I will be able to import self made modules from within this directory

I was under the impression I had to add this to PATH by adding

```
PATH="$HOME/Documents/Python/Programs/:$PATH"
```

To the bottom of my ~/.profile document, was this wrong, and what should I actually be doing to solve this?

Comment: "I am struggling" isn't a very good problem description. What is the `$PATH` variable set to, and how and where do you set it? Better post an MCVE.

Comment: by MVCE, he means "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example", if you're not itching to google.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your PATH e.g. inside ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc depending on where you want to use Python. Add something like this to the end of either of them:

```
PATH="$HOME/Documents/Python/Programs/:$PATH"
```

As stated by the comments, this change will only be take into account, after either restarting a login shell or new start of X session (e.g. newboot). If you need the changes directly, either source the file or export it manually... so

either

source ~/.profile 
source ~/.bashrc

(you could also use the . operator, but this is only working in Bash)

or export the variable

```
export PATH="$HOME/Documents/Python/Programs/:$PATH"
```

It's important to add your custom path before original PATH as the shell will call the 1st file found inside $PATH.

Comment: Forgot to mention that he has to `source` in order for the changes to take effect in the current terminal session. This is a common mistake for new users - sets the PATH but doesn't reopen the terminal so that the changes take effect and wonders why it isn't working. :)

Comment: I added `PATH="$HOME/Documents/Python/Programs/:$PATH"` to the end of .profile, turn my laptop off and on again, and it still just says import error when I try to import anything in a python module

Comment: @DanielJ PATH is not used for determine where to find things for import. Please update your question with code sample or at least some examples what are you doinng